# How to retrieve indices of all visible faces?

Tags: opengl, graphics

Given a mesh loaded as a VBO that is observed by a camera, is there a way to retrieve the indices of all faces that are part of the non-culled part of that mesh (the part that the camera can "see")? To make things simple (I think) no reflection is present in the scene.

---

**Reason:** The motion of the camera will mimic the motion of the sun over a scene. I need to post-process all lit up polygons and check the amount of light they receive.

---

**Update:**

I was able to implement a color map (at least as far as I grasped the concept) but only using the old fixed pipeline.

The way it works is as follows:

- I make the assumption that I have a list of faces with indices from 0 to N. This comes from the fact that faces are normally put in some sort of a list. If I want to access a specific face all I need to do is count X number of times with a constant stride (3 for the case one triangle = one face and 4 for the case where a face is a quad)
- Generate a dictionary (plays the role of my hashmap), where every key is a triplet representing an RGB color (the alpha is useless here since in my case it's all constant). Initially all values are set to nothing. I use a dictionary since it ensures that every color is unique. I exclude black `(0, 0, 0)` since this is the background color I am using. This means I can have up to `16777216 - 1` faces each with a distinct color. The `16777216` is the number `256*256*256` and represents the total number of colors in RGB
- For N faces I count from 0 to N and use the iteration step to assign an face index value to the each key
- In order to see which faces are visible in my view, I render the framebuffer as a texture which I then load into a `PIL.Image`. It allows me to get a trimmed down histogram `getcolors()`, from which I can then simply retrieve all the unique colors in the image thus providing me with the face indices.

The code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
import numpy as np
from csv import writer

from utils import *

DISPLAY_W = 800
DISPLAY_H = 800

def generate_random_rgb_float():
    '''
    Generate a random RGB color represented as a tuple of floats.
    Each component (R, G, B) ranges from 0.0 to 1.0.
    '''
    r, g, b = np.random.randint(255, size=3)
    if [r, g, b] == [0, 0, 0]:  # Make sure that black (used for the background cannot be generated)
        generate_random_rgb_float()

    return (
        round(r/255.0, 6),
        round(g/255.0, 6),
        round(b/255.0, 6)
    )

def generate_random_rgb_byte():
    '''
    Generate a random RGB color represented as a tuple of bytes.
    Each component (R, G, B) ranges from 0 to 255.
    '''
    r, g, b = np.random.randint(255, size=3)
    if [r, g, b] == [0, 0, 0]:  # Make sure that black (used for the background cannot be generated)
        generate_random_rgb_byte()

    return (
        r,
        g,
        b
    )

def generate_colormap(num_colors, format='b'):
    '''
    Generate a hashmap of unique colors as keys and face indices as values

    Parameters:
        num_colors The number of faces to generate the colormap for
                   Assumption: face idx starts from 0 and all indices are consequtive in order

    Returns:
        Dictionary of color, face_idx pairs
    
    '''
    #colors = generate_random_rgb_list(num_colors, format)

    colors = {}

    while len(colors.keys()) < num_colors:
        color = None
        if format == 'b':
            color = generate_random_rgb_byte()
        elif format == 'f':
            color = generate_random_rgb_float()

        if color in colors or color == (0, 0, 0):
            continue
        else:
            colors[color] = None

    for color, face_idx in zip(colors.keys(), range(num_colors)):
        colors[color] = face_idx

    return colors


# Helper function to calculate the frustum scale. 
# Accepts a field of view (in degrees) and returns the scale factor
def calcFrustumScale(fFovDeg):
    degToRad = 3.14159 * 2.0 / 360.0
    fFovRad = fFovDeg * degToRad
    return 1.0 / np.tan(fFovRad / 2.0)  # OLD used math.tan

# Define vertices and faces of your object (cube in this case)
vertices = [
    [1, -1, -1],
    [1, 1, -1],
    [-1, 1, -1],
    [-1, -1, -1],
    [1, -1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1],
    [-1, -1, 1],
    [-1, 1, 1]
]

faces = [
    [0, 1, 2, 3],
    [3, 2, 7, 6],
    [6, 7, 5, 4],
    [4, 5, 1, 0],
    [1, 5, 7, 2],
    [4, 0, 3, 6]
]

# Define a color map for each face index
#color_map = generate_random_rgb_list(6, format='b')
color_map = generate_colormap(6, format='b')


def transform():
    # Ever render call the previous rotation matrix will be multiply with
    # the one below leading to a constant rotation
    glRotatef(1, 3, 1, 1)

def render():
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    for color, face_idx in color_map.items():
        glColor4ub(*color, 255)
        face = faces[face_idx]
        for vertex_idx in face:
            glVertex3fv(vertices[vertex_idx])
    glEnd()

def main():
    display = (DISPLAY_W, DISPLAY_H)

    pygame.init()
    pygame.display.set_caption('OpenGL VAO with pygame')
    pygame.display.set_mode(display, pygame.DOUBLEBUF | pygame.OPENGL | pygame.RESIZABLE)
    pygame.display.gl_set_attribute(pygame.GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4)
    pygame.display.gl_set_attribute(pygame.GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 1)
    pygame.display.gl_set_attribute(pygame.GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, pygame.GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE)

    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE)
    glCullFace(GL_BACK)
    glFrontFace(GL_CW)
    
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
    glDepthMask(GL_TRUE)
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL)
    glDepthRange(0.0, 1.0)

    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH)

    gluPerspective(45, (display[0] / display[1]), 0.1, 50.0)
    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -5)

    capture = False 
    while True:  
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
                w_new, h_new = pygame.display.get_window_size()
                print(w_new, h_new)
                # TODO Reshape viewport and apply new perspective

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_s:
                    capture = True

        transform()
        render()

        if capture:
            capture = False  

            print('Taking screenshot')
            w, h = pygame.display.get_window_size()
            # RGBA
            # Get the depth buffer data
            glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)
            data = glReadPixels(0, 0, w, h, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE)
            image = Image.frombytes("RGBA", (pygame.display.get_window_size()[0], pygame.display.get_window_size()[1]), data)
            image = ImageOps.flip(image) # in my case image is flipped top-bottom for some reason
            image.save('frame_rgba.png', 'PNG')

            faces_idx = []
            # Retrieve the distinct colors from the histogram of the image
            for color in image.getcolors():
                # Convert to list to
                if color[1] == (0, 0, 0, 255): # Skip black since it's the background
                    continue

                # Retrieve just the color without the alpha since that is the stored value in the color map
                color = tuple(color[1][0:3])
                print(color)
                print(color_map)
                face_idx = color_map[color]
                print('Face index:', face_idx)
                faces_idx.append([face_idx])

            faces_idx.sort()

            # DEPTH
            depth_data = glReadPixels(0, 0, w, h, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT)
            # Convert depth data to a numpy array
            depth_array = np.frombuffer(depth_data, dtype=np.float32)
            # Reshape the array to match the window size
            depth_array = np.reshape(depth_array, (h, w))
            # Normalize the depth values to the range [0, 1]
            depth_array = (depth_array - np.min(depth_array)) / (np.max(depth_array) - np.min(depth_array))
            # Convert the depth array to a grayscale image
            depth_image = (depth_array * 255).astype(np.uint8)
            # Flip the image vertically (OpenGL and PIL image have different coord. systems)
            depth_image = np.flipud(depth_image)
            # Create a PIL image from the numpy array
            image = Image.fromarray(depth_image, mode='L')
            # Save the image to a file
            image.save("frame_depth.png")

            # Write visible face index to
            print(faces_idx)
            with open('faces.csv', 'w') as csv_f:
                csv_w = writer(csv_f)
                csv_w.writerow(['face_idx'])
                csv_w.writerows(faces_idx)


        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.wait(10)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

My current problem is migrating this to the programmable pipeline (shaders). I have also switched to array objects.

From what I understand one way to do it is to duplicate the vertices, meaning that if a vertex comes in X number of faces I need X duplicates (and accordingly the face's vertex indices need to be adjusted). This sounds like a plan for small models but I have faces with millions of faces.

Last but not least I am facing a problem with the limitations a color map imposes in regards to how many faces I can have. While 16777215 sounds like a lot, for large GIS models this can be nothing. I am indeed looking into splitting large models into small ones but I had to point that out.

Comment: Make each triangle write its index as a color to a texture?

Comment: So it will be a sort of a color map? I have seen such a thing, although it appears that colors repeat, which for me doesn't make sense. Also with e.g. 24bit you can cover 16.7 million colors. The scenes I am handling have tens of millions of faces (derived from satellite imagery).

Comment: There are texture formats with >24bits per pixel. What do you mean by colors repeating? They'll only repeat if you mess up your rendering.

Comment: I was able to implement it but only using the old fixed pipeline. When it comes to the programmable pipeline I cannot make the shaders and also not sure how to structure my data. Check the updated question. I would like to avoid duplicating vertices if possible, which seems to be what many advise to do in this case since 1)I'm loading my data from OBJ (meaning I will have to insert the extra vertices with all of their attributes somehow) and 2)I am already working with a huge number of vertices (geospatial data) so the more vertices I add the worse it gets.

Comment: If you use a geometry shader, then `gl_PrimitiveID` can be defined and made available to the fragment shader without modifying the original vertex buffer.

Comment: @rbaleksandar 16.7 million colours, yes, but don't forget about the alpha channel.  R8G8B8A8 is 32 bits.  If your render target for the ID pass is 32-bit then you can ID billions of triangles.

Comment: @Wyck I will check the geometry shader. Never used one before. As for the alpha channel that's not entirely true since the way I have implemented it currently alpha of 0 will blend with the background color (black). Unless my approach to the color picking by extracting a histogram of the framebuffer is a totally incorrect approach to this whole thing. :D